# React Native: Dont see FontAwesome or any other expo/vector icons

Tags: react-native, expo

I am facing some problems with FontAwesome icons. (I have tried with MaterialCommunityIcons and normal Icons, but the same result)

They don't appear in the bottom Tab navigation, as also under Social networks. (The other icons are from react-native-settings-page)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the TabNavigation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import HomeNavigator from '../navigation/HomeNavigator';
import NewsNavigator from '../navigation/NewsNavigator';
import settings from '../config/settings';
import i18n from "../locales/i18n";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNavigation(props) {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => {
                let iconName;
                if (route.name === 'Home') {
                    iconName = 'home';
                }
                else if (route.name === 'News') {
                    iconName = 'newspaper';
                }
                // You can return any component that you like here!
                return <MaterialCommunityIcons color={color} icon={iconName} size={25} />;
            },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: settings.colors.activecolor,
            inactiveTintColor: settings.colors.fontcolor,
            activeBackgroundColor: settings.colors.navigation,
            inactiveBackgroundColor:settings.colors.navigation,
        }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" options={{ tabBarLabel: i18n.t('navigation.home')  }} component={HomeNavigator} />
          <Tab.Screen name="News" options={{ tabBarLabel: i18n.t('navigation.news')  }} component={NewsNavigator} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );
}

export default TabNavigation;
```

Here are my colors, but I think they are not making the problem:

```
export default {
    colors: {
        navigation: '#000',
        bgcolor: "#000",
        fontcolor: '#fff',
        activecolor: '#dd163b',
        settingsbackground: '#c3c3c3',
    },
    languages: {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using tabBarIcon as part of the navigator this should be passed to the screen level options like below

```
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: i18n.t('navigation.home'),
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={20} />
      ),
    }}
    component={HomeNavigator}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="News"
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: i18n.t('navigation.news'),
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="newspaper" color={color} size={20} />
      ),
    }}
    component={NewsNavigator}
  />
```

Comment: I dont think this is the problem. In my other application, it was working. I found that solution from the official documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/

Comment: Can you console log and see the iconName and route.name ? and try this approach as well

Comment: done. it is showing the correct icons and routes. it changes also the color of the active tab. I have placed one icon on another screen to test there, and it is also not visible. Strange, because I am using the same lib @expo/vector-icons in my other app

Comment: Did you console log or debug and check the values ? i cant think of a reason for it not to work

Comment: I did console log. I have also tried with deleted node_modules and npm install, nothing changes on any of my screens :(

Comment: you wont have to do npm install if the icon is showing in a different place, but this is weird

Comment: i think is something with the expo and react native versions. On my other application, the versions are different and there I don't have any problems with the icons :(

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( I found similar issues, but the solutions there didn't help me either: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7792